# Aggregate data based on unix time stamp crate database

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I'm very new to SQL and time series database. I'm using crate database ( it think which is used  PostgreSQL).i want to aggregate the data by hour,day ,week and month. Unix time stamp is used to store the data. following is my sample database.

```
|sensorid | reading    | timestamp|
====================================
|1        | 1604192522 | 10       |
|1        | 1604192702 | 9.65     |
|2        | 1605783723 | 8.1      |
|2        | 1601514122 | 9.6      |
|2        | 1602292210 | 10    |
|2        | 1602291611 | 12    |
|2        | 1602291615 | 10    |
```

i tried the sql query using **FROM_UNIXTIME** not supported .
please help me?

im looking the answer for hourly data as follows.

sensorid  ,reading  ,            timestamp

```
1          19.65(10+9.65)        1604192400(starting hour unixt time)
2           8.1                  1605783600(starting hour unix time)
2           9.6                  1601514000(starting hour unix time)
2           32 (10+12+10)        1602291600(starting hour unix time)
```

im looking the answer for  monthly data is like

```
sensorid  ,     reading  ,               timestamp
1           24.61(10+9.65+8.1)       1604192400(starting month unix time)
2           41.6(9.6+10+12+10)       1601510400(starting month unix time)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear to me what you mean by "i want to aggregate the data by hour,day ,week and month".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a unix timestamp to a date/time value using `to_timestamp()`.  You can aggregate along multiple dimensions at the same time using `grouping sets`.  So, you might want:

```
select date_trunc('year', v.ts) as year,
       date_trunc('month', v.ts) as month,
       date_trunc('week', v.ts) as week,
       date_trunc('day', v.ts) as day,
       date_trunc('hour', v.ts) as hour,
       count(*), avg(reading), sum(reading)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (to_timestamp(timestamp))) v(ts)
group by grouping sets ( (year), (month), (week), (day), (hour) );
```

Comment: @junealex . . . This basically does what you ask but the time formats are more readable.

Comment: how to use where clause along with this, for searching  based on sensorid ?

Comment: @junealex . . . a `WHERE` clause would go between the `FROM` clause and the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward approach is:

```
SELECT
    (date '1970-01-01' + unixtime * interval '1 second')::date as date,
    extract(hour from date '1970-01-01' + unixtime * interval '1 second') AS hour,
    count(c.user) AS count
FROM core c
GROUP BY 1,2
```

If you are content with having the date and time in the same column (which would seem more helpful to me), you can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select 
    date_trunc('hour', date '1970-01-01' + unixtime * interval '1 second') as date_hour,
    count(c.user) AS count
FROM core c
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: im really confused with this answer

Comment: SQLParseException[Cannot find data type: date] got this error  when executing the query

Comment: what is date in the query ?

Comment: @junealex: that's the syntax top define a literal date: `date '1970-01-01'` defines a date as of January 1st, 1970.

Comment: can you please change the answer based on  my new edit